# Isomorphism Galois group

Tags: galois-theory

I would like to show that if we take $\mathbb{Q}_p \subset K \subset \overline{K}$ where $K$ is a finite extension and $\overline{K}$ an algebraic closure of $K$ then we have $$Gal(\overline{K} /K)^{ab} \simeq \widehat{(K^{\times})} $$ Where $\widehat{(K^{\times})}$ is the profinite completion of $K^{\times}$.  Any ideas ?

Comment: This is (a theorem from) local class field theory. Look up, say, Milne's http://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/CFT.pdf? (Section 1.10 for that statement.)

Comment: Nice !! Thank you very much !

Comment: Hmm actually still got a problem, because Milne is taking $K$ a finite extension and here in the result I want, nothing tell us that $\overline{K}$ is a finite extension.

Comment: @peterag Do you have any idea ? Cause I am reading a paper of Mochizuki and I don't see how he have some conclusion without making assumption of fitness or that the extensions are Galois.

Comment: I am confused: in the original post, you wrote that $K$ is a finite extension of ${\mathbb Q}_p$. In that situation $\overline K$ will certainly not be a finite extension. Furthermore, if the Gal group has a quotient  iso to $\widehat{K^*}$ (as you want), the group will not be finite, and the extension will also not be finite. Which paper are you reading? Can you give an exact  reference to the issue?

Comment: Actually I am trying to read this one : http://www.kurims.kyoto-u.ac.jp/~motizuki/A%20Version%20of%20the%20Grothendieck%20Conjecture%20for%20p-adic%20Local%20Fields.pdf and this statement is made on page 3.

Comment: Then it is exactly as advertised: in fact M says "from local class field theory," and gives as reference Serre's Corps Locaux. And - again: $\overline K$ is NOT a finite extension of $K$. ( I had been wondering whether you were reading his infamous Inter-Universal Teichmuller papers - phew! - where anything might have been understood - or not. )

Comment: But in Milne's pdf there is this exact result for a finite extension, so I was wondering how did he transpose it to this situation. Because I actually didn't find what he use in Local fields to prove that. I am so sorry I am a young student so please forgive me. Your help is precious thanks.

Comment: It's a bit late in my time zone... I'll try to clarify either tomorrow or over the weekend. On the other hand (and in the meantime!), you might be better off with someone face to face: do you have someone around who knows CFT?

Comment: Actually I can only my advisor in 2 weeks, that's why I post my question here. :/

Comment: Quick comment for the moment -  I think you are misreading Milne and the result. For instance, LCFT, Milne, and your paper say that $\text{Gal} (\overline{{\mathbb Q}_p}/{\mathbb Q}_p)^{ab}$ is isomorphic to $\widehat { {\mathbb Q}^*_p }$ . Now, $\mathbb Q_p$ is of course a finite extension of ${\mathbb Q}_p$ (it's equal), but $\overline {{\mathbb Q}_p }$ is not.  An analogous statement holds for any $K$ which is a finite extension of ${\mathbb Q}_p$. Does this address the confusion?

Comment: Actually are we both speaking about theorem 3.1 in Milne's pdf ?

Comment: sorry - i've been otherwise occupied. I'll get back to you at the end of the day (in 'my' time zone).

Comment: Chapter III, 3.1 = the whole cohomological shabang of LCFT. Sure! Yes, there we have that $L$ is a FINITE gal. extension of $K$: a particular consequence of the big machine is that $K^*/ \text{Nm} L^*$ is canonically iso to $\text{Gal} (L/K)^{ab}$. But, taking limits over the  $L$, we get the iso that you want between the completion $\widehat{K^*}$ and $\text{Gal}(\overline K/K)^{ab}$. Chapter I, section1.10 describes the limit  - the first link above... BTW,  Chap I (Lubin-Tate) gives what you want  without coho, but you need to believe Hasse-Arf (nothing is  for free/easy).

Comment: Okay !! I was also thinking about the fact that it is necesary to use the inverse limit to get this isomorphism. I should verify that this isomorphism is compatible with the inverse system now ! Thank you very much for your help

Comment: I think you've got it, but : rereading what I wrote just now, I see it's misleading. Chap 1, section 1.10 obviously only describes the completion of $K^*$. As you say, one has to check the compatibility of the isos. Best....

Comment: Yep but it should be easy. When you mentionned Lubin-Tate wich book exactly are you talking about ? Having an other proof is always interesting :)

Comment: I meant Chapter 1 of the same notes of Milne. Do read the intro, Chapter 0, which sketches history + outlines what the notes cover. BTW, for altogether different version, Lang's ANT uses Artin's original L-series approach to get global CFT first, and then deduces LCFT (a sketch, I'm sure!). The first proofs of  CFT that I saw were from notes of Neukirch - entirely cohomological. I don't think they  are in print, but they must have followed Artin and Tate (among the inventors of CFT!), or Cassels and Froehlich. There are lots of references. Ask your supervisor for better advice  than mine...

Comment: Lang also has a history section that's fun to read...

Comment: Anyway I will read all this, Thank you very much again.